# Resizable wont work on a div that is Droppable and Resizable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-droppable, jquery-ui-resizable

It all worked fine, now my requiment changed that the div I drop my .draaa items has to be resizable too. So I drop my items in a DIV that is droppable and resizable.

The option containment: '#GridDiv' doesn't work anymore but it worked when the #GridDiv dident have resizable on it. So when I resize my GridDiv the dropped elements should also have resize but not larger the '#GridDiv'.

Anyone have an idea? If you scroll through the code you will understand.

```
    $(".draaa").draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    stop: function(ui, event){
        var stop = $(this).position();
        $(this).attr('data-component-x', stop.left);
        $(this).attr('data-component-y', stop.top);
        }
    });

     $('#GridDiv').resizable();

    $("#GridDiv").droppable({
    accept: '.draaa',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        i ++;
        var getClone = $(ui.draggable).clone();
        getClone.attr("id",i+"_"+getClone.attr('id'));
        var hela_cid =getClone.attr("id");
        var deladcid = hela_cid.split("_");
        var cid = deladcid[2];
        var stop = $(getClone).position();
        var widthpx = getClone.css('width');
        var heightpx = getClone.css('height');
        var width = parseInt(widthpx, 10);
        var height = parseInt(heightpx, 10);

        var draggableDocumentOffset = ui.helper.offset();
        var droppableDocumentOffset = $(this).offset();
        var left = draggableDocumentOffset.left - droppableDocumentOffset.left;
        var top = draggableDocumentOffset.top - droppableDocumentOffset.top;
        getClone.css("left",left);
        getClone.css("top", top);
        getClone.css("position", "absolute");


        $(this).append(getClone);

        $("#GridDiv .draaa").addClass("item");

        $(".item").removeClass("ui-draggable draaa");
        $(".item").draggable({
            containment: '#GridDiv',
            //grid: [10,10],
            stop: function(ui, event){

            var stop = $(this).position();
            $(this).attr('data-component-x', stop.left);
            $(this).attr('data-component-y', stop.top);
        },
        }).resizable({

            helper: "ui-resizable-helper",
```

This dosent work
            //containment: '#GridDiv',

```
            //maxHeight: parseInt(MaxHeight),
            //maxHeight: 300,

            stop: function(event, ui) {
                var width = ui.size.width;
                var height = ui.size.height;
                $('#'+hela_cid).attr('data-component-width', width);
                $('#'+hela_cid).attr('data-component-height', height);
                }
        });


    }

});
```

The line is outcommented. So the .draaa componets I can resize larger then the parent '#GridDiv' and I don't want to..

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found why it dident work :/

```
}).resizable({
            //helper: "ui-resizable-helper",
            containment: '#GridDiv',
```

The helper option made it not happend, why ? i dont know. So i will go with no helper option :)